# Necesito ayuda con for del lenguaje c++

Tags: c++, bucle-for

Necesito alguna explicacion sobre for en c++ que sea apta para un principiante ya que curso la preparatoria y no tengo ni minima idea de como realizar un programa con for. En las imagenes adjuntadas se muestran los programas que debo realizar. La aplicacion que utilizo para programar es DEV C++[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tardas menos en [buscar en Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=c+for&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) que en preguntar aquí :-(

Comment: Tengo 40 años y miopía: no puedo leer tu imagen.

Comment: Pueden hacer zoom

Comment: @Arturo puedo hacer zoom, pero no pienso leer un ejercicio, entenderlo, resolverlo y entregártelo... a no ser que te comprometas a decirle a tu profesor que el ejercicio te lo hice yo y me ponga la nota a mi en lugar de a ti.

Comment: PaperBirdMaster, yo puse los ejercicios con el propósito de que se dieran una idea de lo que ocupo aprender sobre esta sentencia, en ningún momento pedí que me resolvieran alguno. Gracias

Comment: @Arturo Pura excusa. En Google se encuentra mucha información sobre la sentencia for en C++. Lo investigas y lo que no entiendas, lo preguntas aquí. Stackoverflow es una comunidad que resuelve dudas especificas, no hacemos tareas o códigos completo. Por lo tanto, lo ideal es que intentes hacer el ejercicio con lo que hayas investigado, luego editas tu pregunta y añades el código que tengas hecho y ya... Esto demuestra que te has esforzado en resolver el ejercicio. Te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta en stackoverflow?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Un bucle de una forma rápida y mal dicha es: "Algo que se repite". Las veces que se repite la podemos controlar con una variable, para que de un "número de vueltas" determinado. Un ejemplo tonto pero para que te lo imagines es cuando un entrenador le dice a su equipo que de 10 vueltas al campo. El equipo tiene 0 vueltas cuando empieza, y cada vez que pasan por donde empezaron suman una vuelta (vuelta++;), cuando dan 10 vueltas (suman 10 veces una vuelta a las que llevaban) y paran.

La peculiaridad del for es que controlas la variable de las vueltas en la propia declaración del for. Si queremos hacer las vueltas al campo:

```
for(int vueltas = 0; vueltas < 10 ; vueltas++){
    cout<<"El equipo está corriendo \n";
}

cout << "Ya hemos terminado \n";
```

La primera parte (hasta el primer;) inicializa la variable (puedes declararla también como en el ejemplo)
La segunda parte comprueba que no han dado más de 10 vueltas. Si esto es correcto se ejecuta lo que hay dentro del for (en este caso muestra "El equipo está corriendo")

La tercera parte es que suma "una vuelta más" a la variable que controlalas iteraciones del bucle.

Ahora el bucle vuelve a la parte 2. Entonces comprueba cuantas vueltas lleva. Si ya han hecho 10 el bucle para y seguiría con lo que hay fuera del bucle. En este caso se mostraría "Ya hemos terminado"